# resize an imageview with two fingers iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

In my application users can load/take a photo, put it into a frame and move, rotate and scale it as they want.I know how use a uiScrollView as a normal view and load inside of it an image, but in this case the image is large as the view, and i want it is large as i want. How can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for moving and scaling an image.you can just use the following default picker function in UIImagepicker.

```
      picker.editing =YES;
```